# Removing italic or Bold, without removing other formattings

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm working on a scaled down Text Editor. There is a JLabel, which should be made italic, Bold, and different Fonts and so on. That already works, but I have a problem, when the text is italic *and* bold to remove just one of them, when the option is clicked again. E.G. when it's italic and bold and I click on italic again, it also removes the bold formation.

My code looks like this (italic example, bold looks the same):

```
italic.addActionListener(
            e -> {
                if(text.getFont().getStyle() != Font.ITALIC) {
                    Font f = new Font(text.getFont().getName(), text.getFont().getStyle() | Font.ITALIC, text.getFont().getSize());
                    text.setFont(f);
                } else {
                    Font f = new Font(text.getFont().getName(), text.getFont().getStyle() - Font.ITALIC, text.getFont().getSize());
                    text.setFont(f);
                }
            }
        );
```

The only solution I came up with is to check every possible case, but I guess there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the XOR operator, `^` to flip the desired Font style bit.

The mask for italic is 2 and for bold is 1.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestBitFlip extends JPanel {
   private JLabel label = new JLabel("Fubarlicious!");

   public TestBitFlip() {
      add(label);
      add(new JButton(new FontAction("Bold", KeyEvent.VK_B, Font.BOLD)));
      add(new JButton(new FontAction("Italic", KeyEvent.VK_I, Font.ITALIC)));
   }

   private class FontAction extends AbstractAction {
      private int mask;

      public FontAction(String name, int mnemonic, int mask) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
         this.mask = mask;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Font font = label.getFont();
         int style = font.getStyle();
         style ^= mask;
         font = font.deriveFont(style);
         label.setFont(font);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestBitFlip mainPanel = new TestBitFlip();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestBitFlip");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Yea... after I thought about that my self... well... thanks I go criy now a little bit

Comment: @Sascha: no need to cry. You should be proud for figuring this out yourself and without help.

Comment: @Sascha Also, if you want to keep the original font and just derive it by changing the style, use Font.deriveFont().

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels while you're at it, why use magic numbers 1 and 2 instead of Font.BOLD and Font.ITALIC?

Comment: @JBNizet: Sigh, I should never try to answer questions in a caffeine deprived state. Thanks yet again.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing some odd behavior using [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)' bitwise solution in conjunction with HTML labels. I took my own approach using [`Font.deriveFont(Map<? extends Attribute, ?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont-java.util.Map-):

```
public class FontUtils {

    public static Font getBold(Font font, boolean bold) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<TextAttribute, Object> fontAttributes = (Map<TextAttribute, Object>) font.getAttributes();
        fontAttributes.put(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, bold ? TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD : TextAttribute.WEIGHT_REGULAR);
        return font.deriveFont(fontAttributes);
    }

    public static Font getItalic(Font font, boolean italic) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<TextAttribute, Object> fontAttributes = (Map<TextAttribute, Object>) font.getAttributes();
        fontAttributes.put(TextAttribute.POSTURE,
                italic ? TextAttribute.POSTURE_OBLIQUE : TextAttribute.POSTURE_REGULAR);
        return font.deriveFont(fontAttributes);
    }

}
```